# Auto-populate tagging without adding terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

We wish to allow users to tag content using an auto-populate widget for taxonomy terms but *not* be able to add new terms. We are currently using the autocomplete term widget. Permissions available for this field are:
[image]

I see that if I disallow a role from being able to create new terms, they also aren't able to see the widget. I read somewhere that I can use Entity Reference to accomplish this but am not sure how.

[image]

Comment: What type of field is **Tagged**?

Comment: check out [TAC](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_access) "Access control for user roles based on taxonomy categories: ... Two term access types: View tag, Add tag."